# is "Turn Off Airplane Mode" alert deprecated?

Tags: ios, reachability

I think I read somewhere that it was deprecated? and what is the alternatives?

I'm talking about the boolean in the info.plist that says: SBUsesNetwork = YES.

The alert shown says:

> Turn Off Airplane Mode or 
>   Use Wi-Fi to Access Data

It has a really neat "Settings" button which takes you to the settings app.

---

I'm aware of the [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code by Apple which is great. But I don't know how to programmatically show this alert or a similar alert, which can take you to the settings app.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flag "Application uses Wi-Fi" instead to have the message with Settings button for plane mode.

On iPad the message would be shown only if plane mode is turn on (no message if Wi-Fi is turn off). On iPhone the message would be shown in both cases - when Plane mode is turn on or when Wi-Fi is turn off.

**Updated:** For iOs5 you can open settings directly:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

**Update:** The URL above works only in ios 5.0